# Android から Facebook API で投稿すると、 OAuthException (#200) が返ってくる

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

現在 Android から Facebook に投稿しようとしているのですが、投稿する段階で以下のエラーが発生して投稿できません。

```
{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, 
 errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Permissions error}
```

下記のサイトを参考にしながら作っており、ログイン機能までは実装できました。

「[AndroidStudioでFacebook連携アプリを作ろうその１](http://blog.flatfisher.com/2014/10/androidstudiofacebook_23.html)」

Facebook Developers にある App ID や Hash Key の設定も行いました。 Hash Key は以下のように生成しました。

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | \
   openssl sha1 -binary | \
   openssl base64
```

Graph API Explorer で `publish_actions` にもチェックを入れてます。これ以上どうすればいいかわかりません。どのようにすれば Facebook でウォールに投稿することができるようになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 投稿先のウォールはトークンを生成したユーザーのウォールですか？

Comment: Facebook Developerに登録してトークンを生成したユーザと投稿先のウォールは違いました。すみません、投稿先のウォールとトークンを生成したユーザのウォールを一致させるにはどこの設定を変えればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

生成したトークンで投稿できるウォールはFacebookの設定に準じます。

ユーザーAでログインしたトークンであればそのユーザーのウォール、またはそのユーザーの投稿が許可されているウォールへの投稿しかできません。

`/me`からユーザーのIDを取得した上で`/{user-id}/feed`へ投稿するというのが最もベーシックな例かと思います。もしくは`/me/feed`は常に自分自身のウォールへのショートカットになっています。下記にサンプルもあります。

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

  ```
  /* make the API call */
  new Request(
      session,
      "/me/feed",
      null,
      HttpMethod.GET,
      new Request.Callback() {
          public void onCompleted(Response response) {
          /* handle the result */
          }
      }
  ).executeAsync();
  ```

ドキュメントに乗っている例を参考にGraph API Explorerで確認しながら実装するとよいでしょう。

Comment: 投稿先のウォールとトークンを生成したユーザのウォールを一致させると、投稿することができました！本当にありがとうございました！
記載していただいたURLを参考にこれから作りこんでいきたいと思います。